# Plymouth Error Logging

Tags: grub2, plymouth, initramfs

I am working on a Plymouth theme and it seems that it has errors. But instead of any error messages I am seeing a black screen.

Where I find the error messages of plymouth or how I enable them?

Thank you in advance
Fabian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to edit your grub configuration file using:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

look for the line containing "quiet splash" and change it like so:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="splash plymouth:debug"
```

You might have other options there like `kslar` or `vt.handoff=7` leave them in place. The important thing is to remove `quiet` and add `plymouth:debug`.

Save the file and then use:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now when you reboot error messages appear on the boot screen plus a full `plymouth` log is located at:

```
/var/log/plymouth-debug.log
```

Good luck tracing down you errors!